# Difference between calculating partial correlation from multiple regression and regression?

Tags: regression, correlation, multiple-regression, partial-correlation

So I am in a bit of a pickle. The way to calculate partial correlation from regression is through the formula  \begin{equation} \rho_{x\cdot y\cdot z} = r_{x\cdot y\cdot z} = \frac{r_{XY} - r_{XZ}r_{YZ}}{\sqrt{(1-r_{XZ}^2)(1-r_{YZ}^2)}} \end{equation}

Where Y is the response and X is the input and Z is the variable that is controlled. \begin{equation} r_{XY} , r_{YZ}, r_{YX}  \end{equation} are residuals of regression between X and Y, Y and Z and Y and X respectively. In terms of computation X, Y and Z would be vectors of the same length.

My question is: Is this the same way to calculate partial correlation if we use multiple regression where Y and X would be a vector while Z is a matrix with multiple predictors that need to be controlled?

Comment: What partial correlation do you get from multiple regression?